# C++ классы, преобразовать программу

Tags: c++, ооп, классы

Был код, калькулятор римских и арабских чисел. Нужно его преобразовать, чтобы был в 3 файла `main.cpp`, `class.cpp` и `class.h`. Я вроде что-то пытался сделать. Ну собственно классы пихал в заголовочный, функцию из `int main` в `class.cpp`, а в `main.cpp` оставлял только вызов этой функции. В `class.cpp` есть строчка `Number::Number()`, на которую собственно и ругается программа, что-то вроде функция уже имеет текст реализации.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "class.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    class Number * calc;
    calc = new Number();
    getchar();
    delete calc;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**class.cpp**

```
#include "class.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

Number::Number()
{
    Number *l, *r;
    char x[256], y[256], oper;
    int rezult;

    cin >> x >> oper >> y;

    if (x[0] >= '0' && x[0] <= '9')
        l = new ArabicNumber(x);
    else
        l = new RomanNumber(x);

    if (y[0] >= '0' && y[0] <= '9')
        r = new ArabicNumber(y);
    else
        r = new RomanNumber(y);

    switch (oper)
    {
    case '+':
        rezult = l->getValue() + r->getValue();
        break;

    case '-':
        rezult = l->getValue() - r->getValue();
        break;

    case '*':
        rezult = l->getValue() * r->getValue();
        break;

    case '/':
        rezult = l->getValue() / r->getValue();
        break;
    }

    cout << l->getValue() << ' ' << oper << ' ' << r->getValue() << " = " << rezult << endl;
};
```

**class.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

class Number
{
public:
    Number()
    {
        value = 0;
    }

    int getValue() const
    {
        return value;
    }

protected:
    int value;
};

class RomanNumber : public Number
{
public:
    RomanNumber(const char *c)
    {
        if (strcmp(c, "I") == 0)
            value = 1;
        else if (strcmp(c, "II") == 0)
            value = 2;
        else if (strcmp(c, "III") == 0)
            value = 3;
        else if (strcmp(c, "IV") == 0)
            value = 4;
        else if (strcmp(c, "V") == 0)
            value = 5;
        else if (strcmp(c, "VI") == 0)
            value = 6;
        else if (strcmp(c, "VII") == 0)
            value = 7;
        else if (strcmp(c, "VIII") == 0)
            value = 8;
        else if (strcmp(c, "IX") == 0)
            value = 9;
        else if (strcmp(c, "X") == 0)
            value = 10;
    }
};

class ArabicNumber : public Number
{
public:
    ArabicNumber(const char *c)
    {
        value = atoi(c);
    }
};
```

Comment: А почему вы приложили работающий текст к вопросу? Доктор, у меня тут все болит, вот я привел друга, у которого все нормально - посмотрите его и скажите, чем я болен...

Comment: Ну вообще я попросил просто её переделать под работающую с 3мя файлами только) Сейчас скину что наделал

Comment: Поменял на свою, которая не работает

Answer (score 1):

Ну и что вы привели в качестве кода? Вполне нормально компилируемый текст. С единственной проблемой - если `oper` будет неверным - `rezult` будет содержать не пойми что.

Откуда же нам знать, какие ошибки вы наделали при разделении текста на части?..

Скорее всего, оставили в заголовочном файле определение

```
class Number
{
public:
    Number()
    {
        value = 0;
    }
```

Но при этом зачем-то в .cpp-файле еще раз записали определение `Number::Number()`.

Но чтоб отвечать уверенно - надо видеть соответствующий текст.

Comment: Поменял программу на то, что сделал неработающее

Comment: Ну все так и есть, как я написал - у вас один раз конструктор `Number::Number()` определен в объявлении класса, второй раз - в `class.cpp`. Уберите *определение* из объявления класса.

Comment: Подскажите, что именно убрать нужно?)

Comment: {
        value = 0;
    }
Если вот это, то убрал, программа запустилась, но значение не возвращается, то есть ничего не считает, а просто бесконечный ввод происходит